# Hide application icon from task bar

Tags: python, gtk

I am trying to hide the application icon from the task bar.

[image]

So far I tried those

```
self.window.set_skip_pager_hint(True)
```

and

```
self.window.set_type_hint(Gdk.WindowTypeHint.UTILITY)
```

and

```
self.window.set_type_hint(Gdk.WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_DOCK)
```

but neither works. I use official GTK+ bindings for python. Could anyone point the resource where I can find the solution?

Comment: I was trying to hide my window from the taskbar on windows 10 with msys2 without success `self.window.set_type_hint(Gdk.WindowTypeHint.UTILITY)` finally made it vanish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`set_skip_pager_hint()` is for the Alt-Tab dialog. You want `set_skip_taskbar_hint()` instead.